# understanding Available screen width vs. smallest Width

Tags: android

the [documentation states](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) the following:

minimum screen width - The fundamental size of a screen, as indicated by the shortest dimension of the available screen area
Available screen width - Specifies a minimum available width in dp units at which the resources should be used—defined by the  value.

Unless I am missing something, they seem to be the exact same thing.. can someone explain the difference ?

Answer (score 8):

In short, the main difference is that the `smallestWidth` does not consider a device orientation. No matter what orientation, if the device has width at least, let's say, 600dp then, for instance, some resources can be applied.

On the other hand `availableWidth` considers the current available width.

Hope that clears your confusion. If not, I would advise to test is directly on a device.